# How to assign values to deck of cards images and then compare them in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I assign values to a deck of cards? Like A is high and 2 is low with images named c-2 to c-53?

This is my code so far, so I need to assign values to the numbers and also colours of the specific cards images(4 colours), and then compare the two to a correct or false statement.

*For example, 2 is the lowest, A is the highest, A and 2 mean choose a colour, 7 means play the same pile and if the same card comes up it is discarded.*

```
    let shuffled = (2...53).shuffled()

    let leftNumber = shuffled[0]

    let rightNumber = shuffled[1]

    let player1Deck = shuffled[2]

    let player2Deck = shuffled[3]

    leftPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(leftNumber)")
    rightPile.image = UIImage(named: "c\(rightNumber)")
    player1Cards.image = UIImage(named: "c\(player1Deck)")
    player2Cards.image = UIImage(named: "c\(player2Deck)"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, but I would suggest that you start by creating an appropriate data structures to represent a deck of cards.  Something like:

```
struct Deck {
    enum Suite: String {
        case clubs = "Clubs"
        case diamonds = "Diamonds"
        case hearts = "Hearts"
        case spades = "Spades"

    }

    struct Rank {
        let name: String
        let faceValue: Int
        let rankValue: Int
    }

    private var allSuites:[Suite] = [.clubs,.diamonds,.hearts,.spades]
    private var allRanks = [Rank(name: "Ace", faceValue: 1,rankValue:13), Rank(name: "Two", faceValue: 2,rankValue: 1),Rank(name: "Three", faceValue: 3,rankValue: 2),Rank(name: "Four", faceValue: 4,rankValue:3 ),Rank(name: "Five", faceValue: 5,rankValue: 4),Rank(name: "Six", faceValue: 6,rankValue: 5),Rank(name: "Seven", faceValue: 7,rankValue: 6),Rank(name: "Eight", faceValue: 8,rankValue: 7),Rank(name: "Nine", faceValue: 9,rankValue: 8),Rank(name: "Ten", faceValue: 10,rankValue: 9),Rank(name: "Jack", faceValue: 10,rankValue: 10),Rank(name: "Queen", faceValue: 10,rankValue: 11),Rank(name: "King", faceValue: 10,rankValue: 12) ]

    private let cards: [Card]
    private var availableCards: [Card]
    init() {
        var cards = [Card]()
        for suite in allSuites {
            for rank in allRanks {
                cards.append(Card(suite: suite, rank: rank))
            }
        }
        self.cards = cards
        self.availableCards = cards
    }

    mutating public func shuffle() {
        self.availableCards = self.cards.shuffled()
    }

    mutating public func drawCard() -> Card? {
        if let card = self.availableCards.first {
            self.availableCards.removeFirst()
            return card
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var top: Card? {
        get {
            return availableCards.first
        }
    }

    var remaining: Int {
        get {
            return availableCards.count
        }
    }
}

struct Card: Comparable, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    let suite: Deck.Suite
    let rank: Deck.Rank

    var image: UIImage {
        get {
            let imageName = "\(rank.name)\(suite.rawValue)"
            return UIImage(named: imageName) ?? UIImage()
        }
    }

    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rank.faceValue == rhs.rank.faceValue && lhs.suite == rhs.suite
    }

    static func < (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rank.rankValue < rhs.rank.rankValue
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "\(self.rank.name) of \(self.suite.rawValue)"
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
var deck = Deck()
print(deck.top ?? "Empty")
deck.shuffle()
print(deck.top ?? "Empty")
while let card = deck.drawCard() {
    print(card)
}
deck.shuffle()
if let first = deck.drawCard(), second = deck.drawCard() {
    if first > second {
        print("\(first) is higher than \(second)")
    } else if first < second {
        print("\(first) is lower than \(second)")
    } else {
        print("\(first) is the same value as \(second)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Paulw11  I appreciate it! I think i understand some of it but I am a newb ha and don't know how to integrate it with the code I already have or do I just not use it at all now? What areas do i need to add my code and images into, do i need to rename my images? And do i need to reconnect my outlets? is it just the 'struct Card: Comparable' and bottom code i need to add to? Sorry for the broad question i realize now i need to be more specific. Thanks again

Comment: i've tried multiple things to try an assign images to the code you provided but no luck, any suggestion you can give will be much appreciated thanks

Comment: The `Card` struct already has an `image` property that will return a `UIImage` - you just need the assets in your asset catalog with the appropriate name - For example `10Clubs` or `2Hearts` etc